# what is the usage of getOrElse in scala

Tags: scala

I'd like to get values from map like that

```
user_TopicResponses.put(
        "3"+"_"+topicid, 
        Access.useradVectorMap.getOrElse(
                "3"+"_"+topicid, 
                Access.useradVectorMap.getOrElse("3"+"_"+"0"),
                Array(0.0)
        )
)
```

What means if key in map value will be get, of else key is set to `"3+"0"` and value will also be get.
but it will be reported that:

```
too many arguments for method getOrElse: (key: String, default: => B1)B
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up parentheses a bit :

`Access.useradVectorMap.getOrElse("3"+"_"+"0"),Array(0.0)` shoud in fact be
`Access.useradVectorMap.getOrElse("3"+"_"+"0",Array(0.0))`

It should be ok after that !

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would suggest, at least for debugging purposes, to break your one statement into multiple statements. Your problem stems from a missing/misplaced parentheses. This would be much easier to see if you split your code up.

Secondly, it's good practice to use a variable or function for any repeated code, it makes it far easier to change and maintain (I like to use them for any hard coded value that might change later as well).

In order to only calculate the `secondaryValue` only if the `primaryValue.getOrElse(...)` goes to the "else" value, you can use a `lazy val`, which only evaluates if needed:

```
val primaryKey = "3_" + topicid
val secondaryKey = "3_0"
val secondaryDefaultValue = Array(0.0)
lazy val secondaryValue = Access.useradVectorMap.getOrElse(secondaryKey, secondaryDefaultValue )
val primaryValue = Access.useradVectorMap.getOrElse(primaryKey, secondaryValue)
user_TopicResponses.put(primaryKey, primaryValue)
```

This code is far easier to read and, more importantly, far easier to debug